# Symfony 1.4 on server

Tags: php, apache, symfony1, symfony-1.4

i make my apps in Symfony 1.4 on localhost. Here is OK, but if i upload all files in www server then if i open:

**www.mysite.com/**

then i have error:

> symfony PHP Framework page not found Oops! An Error Occurred The
>   server returned a "500 Internal Server Error".
>
> Something is broken
>       Please e-mail us at [email] and let us know what you were doing
>   when this error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry
>   for any inconvenience caused. What's next
>
> ```
>     Back to previous page
>     Go to Homepage
> ```

but if i open 
**www.mysite.com/frontend_dev.php**

then all is good.

where i must search error? how can i fix it?

Answer (score 3):

You must clear the cache.

```
php symfony cc
```

Answer (score 1):

did you set the permissions for the cache and the logs? and the most important, cache cleared `./symfony cc`?

Answer (score 1):

In your config file change the  envirment to Live currently you are on development envirment

Answer (score 1):

you can check the url by hitting www.mysite.com/frontend_prod.php

Answer (score 0):

First try the "symfony cc" for cache clearing. If it doesn't work check your configured apache-errorfile.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you upload files to your webserver, I guess that may be you don't have shell access. So you'll need to clear the content of cache folder.

Also log and cache folder must exist and be writable by the webserver

Answer (score 0):

You must deploy your application for use anywhere else than localhost (because you are in 'development').

Check this out: http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/22#chapter_22_deploying

Answer (score 0):

If you have ssh access to your web server type:

```
php symfony cc
```

If not make sure to clear your cache folder. Then everything will be gone well.

Answer (score -1):

you must edit the routing.yml file.

```
# default rules
homepage:
  url:   /
  param: { module: your_module, action: your_action}
```